# What is wrong with my template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I want to provide several conversion functions that transform my custom struct into other types. These functions should be overloaded by the return return type. I have tried template specialization like follows.

I get this compiler error message:

`class cv::Rect __cdecl convert<class cv::Rect >(struct MyRect const &)"  already defined in CallerCode.obj`.

What is wrong with my code?

*MyRect.h*

```cpp
struct MyRect
{
    float lux, luy, rlx, rly;

    float width() const;
    float height() const;
};
```

*Library code*

```cpp
class cv::Rect;
struct OtherRect;
```

*Conversion.h*

```cpp
template<typename T> T convert(const MyRect& r);

template<> cv::Rect convert<cv::Rect>(const MyRect& r)
{
    return cv::Rect(r.lux, r.luy, r.width(), r.height());
}

template<> OtherRect convert<OtherRect>(const MyRect& r)
{
    return OtherRect(r.lux, r.luy, r.rlx, r.rly);
}
```

*Calling code*

```cpp
MyRect r{ 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };
const cv::Rect cr = convert<cv::Rect>(r);
```

Comment: What is `OtherRect`? Also why `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: @tadman `float` because of openCV I think...

Comment: @JHBonarius Good point. Thought it was just unnecessary stinginess.

Comment: @tadman `OtherRect` i made up for demonstration purposes to show how I want to use different types. `float` vs `double` is not relevant to the question (could also be `int` or any type, the problem stays the same).

Comment: I'm just asking because if that's an alias for the same thing that would explain a lot. If it's a completely different type worth saying that. I mentioned `float` because quite often later down the road people start griping about a lack of precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full specializations are no longer template functions, so no longer implicitly `inline`.

You have to add `inline`

```
template<> inline cv::Rect convert<cv::Rect>(const MyRect& r)
{
    return cv::Rect(r.lux, r.luy, r.width(), r.height());
}
```

or split declaration in header and definition in cpp file

```
// Declaration: in header
template<> cv::Rect convert<cv::Rect>(const MyRect&);
```

```
// Definition: in cpp file
template<> cv::Rect convert<cv::Rect>(const MyRect& r)
{
    return cv::Rect(r.lux, r.luy, r.width(), r.height());
}
```

Comment: But my syntax is correct? So moving the specialized functions into .cpp file is enough?

Comment: @Sparkofska: You need the **declaration** in header.